# Applescript text delimiter replace line to /n

Tags: applescript, text

I'm trying to remove line and replace them by "\n" (to them add the final text in javascript with actual line)

```
set myCaseNote to "e.g
here
and
there"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {return & linefeed, return, linefeed, character id 8233, character id 8232}
set myCaseNote to text items of myCaseNote
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" "}
set myCaseNote to myCaseNote as text
```

I can manage to remove the line but I can't replace them with the text "\n", how can I proceed ?

Comment: Tell us what happens when you try to add `\n`.  What goes wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you didn't actually say what's going wrong when you try to insert `\n` into your string, I had a little think and then I remembered that there's a setting in *Script Editor*:

[image: Script Editor settings on macOS]

So, if I'm guessing along the right lines here, I'm suspecting you currently have this option unchecked, which means that whenever you try to type an escaped line-break like `"\n"`, *Script Editor* automatically replaces it with a physical line-break whilst you're editing, which then leads to your syntax error issues with JavaScript.

[ *Don't forget to escape the newline character twice before sending it to your JavaScript code if doing so **within** AppleScript: `\\n`.  If you are entering it directly into the developer console inside the web browser, the single escape `\n` is fine.* ]

So, **Option 1**, is to adjust this formatting setting in *Script Editor*.  **Option 2** is to stop using *Script Editor* and use something like [***Script Debugger***](https://latenightsw.com) or [***Atom***](https://atom.io).

Comment: Yes, the Formation Option change everything alright.  everything it's working now, I can remove the line and add them back with this as \\n so I can sent them to my javascript (the previous question that you also solved) thank you